# Is it possible to make ls ignore Windows hidden files?

Tags: files, windows, ls

I'm using the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) libraries on a Windows 7 machine. I do not like that the `ls` command shows NTFS hidden files. I've found two methods to hide these files.

One solution is to mount the partition using the `hide_hid_files` mount option in linux, which is not useful for me because I'm using Windows.

The other solution involves using `.hidden` files, which would be burdensome to manually maintain.

It should be possible to write a script that creates these files on the fly and then call `ls` afterward. Should I write the script I described or is there a better way to achieve the desired output? Does anyone have a script for this situation already made?

Comment: if you perform "ls -la" on these files is there anything that makes them stand out? wondering if you could create an alias for ls with a grep...

Comment: No, ls doesn't list NTFS attributes at all.

Comment: what is the output of mount? wondering if you can do a cheeky remount even though you are using gnuwin32 and didn't mount...

Comment: `mount` is not part of GnuWin32 or Windows.

Comment: no idea then, goodluck

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about Windows than Unix or Linux — even though it's about using GNU tools, the specifics relate to NTFS.